# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible || using Firestore, Redux, createAsyncThunk

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, redux, redux-thunk

I am getting that error when trying to subscribe to realtime updates on firestore via onSnapshot(), using it inside the async function of createAsyncThunk with redux react tools.

The function doesnt wait for the forEach to finish.
I have tried a for of loop, but does not work with onSnapshot.

This is my createAsyncFunction.

```
export const getAuctions = createAsyncThunk(
    'auctions/getAuctions',
    async () => {
        const auctionRef = collection(db, "auctions");
        const fetched = [];
        onSnapshot(auctionRef, (querySnapshot) => {
            for (const doc of querySnapshot.docs) {
                fetched.push(doc.data());
            };
        })
        return fetched
    }
)
```

This is called from a dispatch() inside a useEffect one time when the app loads.
Any idea?!

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There's three problems here:

- `onSnapshot` runs long *after* this async thunk returns, not *during* the thunk. So, you're actually returning an empty array "now", and it won't have any data inside.
- When the `onSnapshot` *does* run, it tries to mutate the `fetched` array... but that array reference has already been added into the Redux state and frozen by Immer.  So, the JS engine is throwing an error because you can't mutate a frozen array.
- On top of that, `onSnapshot` can apparently run *multiple* times, whereas a thunk is intended to run *once* (per time that you dispatched it).

I'm not familiar with Firebase's API, but you should try to use something that returns data "now", along the lines of (fake code): `const data = await collection(db, "auctions").get()`

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks a lot for your detailed answer.
 
I thought somehow the onSnapshot would subscribe once in the thunk and then do the further updates once initializated.

Everything works fine with other firestore method getDocs() and a for of loop. But then I loose realtime updates.

Will try to find a solution.
Thanks!

Comment: If you need to subscribe and dispatch something _many_ times, you may want to look into using the RTK "listener middleware" instead: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware